# Select all fields with duplicate entries in a column based on each similar value in another column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

Sample table

```
Table1

Column A, Column B, Column C
Blah, 3, Blue
Foo, 3, Blue
Bar, 2, Blue
Joy, 1, Red
To, 2, Red
World, 2, Red
```

I want to find all values column b that are the same for each column c that is the same.  My end goal is to create a trigger that keeps track of these entries and notify users that a conflict requires attention.

so results should be like

```
Blah,3,Blue
Foo,3,Blue
To,2,Red
World,2,Red
```

As in within all Blues 3 is duplicated, in all reds 2 is duplicated.... so on.

Comment: In title you have a and b, in question b and c. And in your table neither ever matches each other. Please restate your question.

Comment: And please show the expected output for the given input data.

Answer (score 0):

If I am interpreting your question properly, you could use a group by statement such as

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*)
, b
, c
FROM table1
GROUP BY b, c
```

Which will give you a count of the rows, and if there is a duplicate, then the count will be greater than 1. You can then filter this down to only return rows that have more than 1 for this count, so the final query might be (with help from @ypercube) :

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) totalCount
, b
, c
FROM table1
GROUP BY b, c
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: You can do this with `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`, no need for nested query.

Comment: That will find all the column b that have more than one match but I want to do that for every C.

Comment: That will find all rows where columns b and c as a pair are the same, so if two rows have b=2 and c=Blue, they will be returned

Answer (score 0):

> My end goal is to create a trigger that keeps track of these entries and notify users that a conflict requires attention.

I can't tell what "requires attention".  Is it the fact that the pair {3,blue}  should appear only once, that it may be associated with **Blah** or **Foo**, but not both?   If so, declare a `UNIQUE` constraint on that pair of columns, and save yourself the trouble of writing a trigger.  An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure.

Triggers are not meant for advice; they are meant to enforce constraints that cannot be declared.  Using them for any other purpose may be tempting, but will end in tears.